# Apostroph encoded as an escape character

Tags: php, html, swiftmailer

I have a PHP script that grabs data from an HTML form and sends it in an email with SwiftMailer.
When a user enters apostrophe or quotes into an input field (textarea), the email looks something like this:

> Form input:
>   Husband's PLD

Email received received:
Husband\'s PLD

Form input:
pld's "snack" "old"

Email received:
pld\'s \"snack\" \"old\"

There is some validation and sanitation going on in my script:

```
if ($_POST['form_message'] != "") {
        $form_message = filter_var($_POST['form_message'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_NO_ENCODE_QUOTES);
        if ($_POST['form_message'] == "") {
            $errors .= 'Please enter a valid comment.<br/><br/>';
        }
    } else {
        $errors .= 'Please enter your comment.<br/>';
    }
```

Here is the Swiftmailer part:

```
$message->setBody("Here is the information submitted to
```

www.polycystic-kidneydisease.com/html/contact_email.php 
from $ip on $date.\n\n
--------------------------------\n\n
name: $name \n\n
email address: $email \n\n
subject: $form_subject \n\n
comment: $form_message");

How do I fix it?
Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like [`magic_quotes_gpc`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php) is enabled. If you can disable it, you may want to do so; if not, use [`stripslashes()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) on the input before doing your filtering.

Comment: Do you mean the Swiftmailer part would look something like this:

Comment: $message->setBody("Here is the information submitted to 
www.polycystic-kidneydisease.com/html/contact_email.php 
from $ip on $date.\n\n
--------------------------------\n\n
name: $name \n\n
email address: $email \n\n
subject: $form_subject \n\n
comment: stripslashes($form_message)");

Comment: Simpler would be: `$form_message = filter_var(stripslashes($_POST['form_message']),` ...

Comment: With no FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING or FILTER_FLAG_NO_ENCODE_QUOTES?

Comment: With them. There's a reason why the snippet I posted ends with a `,` - I meant for you to only add/change to the first part, leaving the rest as it was.

Comment: Got it.
Thank you a million, Amber!